# Eclipse Javadoc Compiler Warnings from Command Line

Tags: java, eclipse, command-line, javadoc, compiler-warnings

I recently moved from Eclipse to another IDE. One thing I'm really missing is configurable [compiler warnings for various Javadoc problems](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/preferences/java/compiler/ref-preferences-errors-warnings.htm).

As my IDE can use the Eclipse compiler - and I know that it is possible to configure all kinds of [general compiler warnings from the command line](http://help.eclipse.org/ganymede/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/guide/jdt_api_compile.htm) - I was wondering if it is possible to configure the Javadoc warnings like this as well.

I'm especially looking for a way to configure the following settings:

- `Missing Javadoc tags` for methods of a certain visibility
- `Missing Javadoc comments` for methods of a certain visibility

Answer (score 1):

You could do this either through an external tool (like Eclipse likely does), or use a doc-checking doclet for this. The standard doclet (or the javadoc core) has no options here.